# Angular 7 call service with promise that call function inside composent that call another function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 7 and I have a component with service:

In my component I have this function that calls a service function:

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
[...]

public deleteCar(nameCar: string)
  {
    this.carService.deleteCar(nameCar, this.errorDeleteCar, this.successDeleteCarAndUpdateView);
  }

[...]
}
```

The service function is:

```
export class CarService
{
[...]

public deleteCar(offerId: string, errorDeleteCar: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => void, successDeleteCarAndUpdateView: (nameCar: string) => void):void
  {
    this.deleteFavoriteService(nameCar)
      .subscribe(
        () =>
        {
          successDeleteCarAndUpdateView(nameCar);
        },
        (error) =>
        {
          errorDeleteCar(error);
        }
      );
  }

[...]
}
```

The function `successDeleteCarAndUpdateView` in my component is:

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
[...]
public successDeleteCarAndUpdateView(nameCar: string): void
{

   console.log("This is printed");
   this.updateCache(nameCar);
   [...]
 }

public updateCache(nameCar: string): void
{

   [...]
 }

[...]
}
```

I cannot call  `updateCache` and I have this message:

```
ERROR TypeError: this is undefined
```

But the console.log works.

But when I call the function in a normal way, for instance from the constructor I have not problem.

The full message error is:

```
ERROR TypeError: this is undefined
    successDeleteCarAndUpdateView profile.component.ts:795
    deleteCar car.service.ts:62
    RxJS 11
        __tryOrUnsub
        next
        _next
        next
        _next
        next
        _next
        next
        notifyNext
        _next
        next
    Angular 8
        onLoad
        invokeTask
        onInvokeTask
        invokeTask
        runTask
        invokeTask
        invokeTask
        globalZoneAwareCallback
```

Comment: Can you please share the entire error message? (including stacktrace)

Comment: Done, I have insert the full error stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could fix it by doing this:

```
this.carService.deleteCar(nameCar, this.errorDeleteCar.bind(this), this.successDeleteCarAndUpdateView.bind(this));
```

so that the functions have this correct `this` context bound to them...

or this would work too, as arrow functions will keep the proper `this` context:

```
this.carService.deleteCar(nameCar, (err) => this.errorDeleteCar(err), (resp) => this.successDeleteCarAndUpdateView(resp));
```

but instead i'd recommend a restructure like so in your service...

```
// return the observable.
public deleteCar(offerId: string):void
{
  return this.deleteFavoriteService(nameCar);
}
```

in component, subscribe...

```
  public deleteCar(nameCar: string)
  {
    this.carService.deleteCar(nameCar).subscribe(
      (response) => this.successDeleteCarAndUpdateView(response),
      (err) => this.errorDeleteCar(err), 
    );
  }
```

updating the view is the job of the component, so leave it in the component. Let the service do its job, calling the API.

Answer (score 1):

The context of `this` in `public successDeleteCarAndUpdateView()` has been lost because the method is invoked as a callback within the service `.subscribe`.

Two things you could try here.

1. bind `this` to the method itself to preserve its Component context

```
export class ProfileComponent {
  constructor(
    ... stuff ...
  ) {
    this.successDeleteCarAndUpdateView.bind(this);
  }
}
```

2. Refactor the service to simply make the HTTP call and hand the Component back an Observable that it can subscribe too. This can help maintain context and avoid callback issues like this.